# Custom fields are not showing updated value when update in field updated event, Why?

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I have added custom fields in customization form using the customization form, steps i have added:
1) Go to shipment form and select Transaction Grid.
2) Select Add fields.
3) Select custome and Add 4 fields and save and publish.
4) Add all 4 fields and select used and save.
5) and publish again and all 4 columns are visible.
6) I have added a user fields name Aloow (PXDBBool), UsrPClocation(Location) and UsrPCwarehouse(Site), 
   and i set the below attribute in warehour and location.
7) But on SOSHipLine_InventotyID_FieldUpdate event, i am setting Allow, location, warehouse all 3 values, but values are not showing in Grid, what is the resoon?

#region UsrQCSiteID

```
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "PC Warehouse")]      
    [SiteAvail(typeof(SOShipLine.inventoryID), typeof(SOShipLine.subItemID))]       
    [PXUIRequired(typeof(Where<usrAllow, Equal<True>>))]
    [PXUIEnabled(typeof(Where<usrAllow, Equal<True>>))]
    [PXDefault()]
    public virtual int? UsrPCSiteID {
        get; set;
    }
    public abstract class usrPCSiteID:PX.Data.BQL.BqlInt.Field<usrPCSiteID> {
    }

    #endregion UsrPCSiteID

    #region UsrPCLocationID

    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "PC Location")]       
    [SOLocationAvail(typeof(SOShipLine.inventoryID), typeof(SOShipLine.subItemID), typeof(SOShipLineExt.usrPCSiteID), typeof(SOLine.tranType), typeof(SOShipLine.invtMult))]

    [PXUIRequired(typeof(Where<usrQCRequired, Equal<True>>))]
    [PXUIEnabled(typeof(Where<usrQCRequired, Equal<True>>))]
    [PXDefault()]
    public virtual int? UsrPCLocationID {
        get; set;
    }
    public abstract class usrPCLocationID:PX.Data.BQL.BqlInt.Field<usrPCLocationID> {
    }

    #endregion UsrPCLocationID
```

#region Allow

```
    [PXDBBool]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Allow")]

    public virtual bool? UsrAllow {
        get; set;
    }
    public abstract class usrAllow:PX.Data.BQL.BqlBool.Field<usrAllow> {
    }

    #endregion
```

IS SOShipLine allow updating custom values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The steps that you described look correct.

I recreated this scenario locally:

1 - My DAC extension looks as follows:

```
  public class SOShipLineExt : PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.SO.SOShipLine>
  {
    #region UsrPCSiteID
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "PC Warehouse")]      
    [SiteAvail(typeof(SOShipLine.inventoryID), typeof(SOShipLine.subItemID))]       
    public virtual int? UsrPCSiteID {
        get; set;
    }
    public abstract class usrPCSiteID:PX.Data.BQL.BqlInt.Field<usrPCSiteID> {
    }
    #endregion UsrPCSiteID

    #region UsrPCLocationID
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "PC Location")]       
    [SOLocationAvail(typeof(SOShipLine.inventoryID), typeof(SOShipLine.subItemID), typeof(SOShipLineExt.usrPCSiteID), typeof(SOShipLine.tranType), typeof(SOShipLine.invtMult))]
    public virtual int? UsrPCLocationID {
        get; set;
    }
    public abstract class usrPCLocationID:PX.Data.BQL.BqlInt.Field<usrPCLocationID> {
    }
    #endregion UsrPCLocationID


#region Allow
    [PXDBBool]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Allow")]
    public virtual bool? UsrAllow {
        get; set;
    }
    public abstract class usrAllow:PX.Data.BQL.BqlBool.Field<usrAllow> {
    }
    #endregion
  }
```

**Notes about the DAC Extension:**

- I removed references to PXUIEnabled and PXUIRequired. If you are looking to disable the *Site* and the *Location* based on the checkbox's value, I recommend you manage this logic in the RowSelected event. (it may be feasible with your approach but I have not used it before)
- The PXDefault references were also removed, given that in most cases the Shipment is created directly from the Sales Order page. As you have it right now, the field is mandatory but no default value is being assigned which will cause an error. You have 2 options: 1) indicate the value in the PXDefault() attribute, or 2) Set the property *PXPersistingCheck.Nothing*.
- Note that your SOLocationAvail attribute has an error in the 4th parameter. You should use *typeof(SOShipLine.tranType)* instead of *typeof(SOLine.tranType)*. This was generating an error when the shipment was created from the SO.

2 - My FieldUpdated event looks as follows:

```
  public class SOShipmentEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<SOShipmentEntry>
  {
    protected virtual void SOShipLine_InventoryID_FieldUpdated(PXCache cache, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e)
  {
    if (e.Row == null) return;
    SOShipLine line = (SOShipLine)e.Row;
    SOShipLineExt lineExt = cache.GetExtension<SOShipLineExt>(line);

    if (lineExt != null)
    {
      lineExt.UsrAllow = true;
      lineExt.UsrPCSiteID=154;
      lineExt.UsrPCLocationID=155;        
    }
  }
  }
```

**Notes about the Graph extension:**

- I hard-coded the Warehouse and Location values. I recommend you do the same on your end while testing is being done, just make sure that the IDs exist in your DB, or that you query the CD value and then use its corresponding ID value.

**Results:**

When the Shipment is created from a SO, the values are being correctly assigned:
[image]

Comment: Thanks Femando, I am doing same as you suggested, But still no luck. I found a mistake, PCSite and PCLicationId both are not showing as selector when i check into the customization project, when i tried to set selector and save then its rollback and reset with NumericEdit, Any suggestion why?

Comment: I feel, property is not binding properly that's-why value are not updating. But when i set the value like below then it set the value    
 this.Base.SetValueExt("Transactions", shipLine, "UsrPCSiteID",  1);

But statement shipLine.UsrPCSiteID = 1; doesn't set value.
Do you know the reason?

Comment: @amit remove the fields from the page via the Customization project interface. Then try to add them again - you will see 3 options per field:. 2 TextEdits and 1 SegmentMask Make sure you select the "SegmentMask"

Comment: Troubleshoot the error by narrowing down the potential causes of error: i) unpublish other customization packages, ii) keep the field DACs as simple as possible. iii) use a simple PXTextEdit for testing purposes, iv) test it in another Acumatica dev instance, etc. You can also copy/paste my code samples above. Once it starts working for you, you can add additional attributes.

Comment: I have used same approach in another form and it work, But why not this form, Before Unpublish/republish, I want to know the reason of issue.

Comment: it should be working on that page as well. It did on my local env. Unpublish/republish is one troubleshooting step that I would follow. Try to test it in a fresh environment free of customizations instead

Comment: How to unpublish?

Comment: OK, I can see the unpublish option.

Comment: @amit any luck with this?

Comment: Yes, Unpublish the project and then remove all custom fields and then publish. then again build the project and add custom fields again and re-publish then solved. But its not a good practice.